# How to set up React App on server so that I have links how I want them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I made a React WebShop for testing using a tutorial and wanted to integrate it into  my website to test, but unfortunately every time I do so, the app gets messed up. Meaning the links make no sense.
For instance I would like that if I type in mywebsite.com/Shop that the    Shop is displayed. But at the moment when I enter the directory where the app sits (address above), I get back the default component for the error code 404 and not my product overview.

Sorry, but I can't really explain what I mean very well.

Git: https://github.com/Arborem123/webshop

Comment: Right now your base path("/") points to your product list, but "/shop" is not declared as a route. Your code is working as expected if "/shop" renders your default component.

Comment: So, where exactly do I have to make changes now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your routing is setup like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={ProductList} />
  <Route path="/details" component={Details} />
  <Route path="/cart" component={Cart} />
  <Route component={Default} />
</Switch>
```

There is no `/shop` path exposed to the router, so it will end up rendering your `Default` component when it falls through the `Switch` without matching any other paths. If you want to expose a `/shop` route, you'll need to change your `Switch` to something like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/shop" component={ProductList} />
  <Route path="/details" component={Details} />
  <Route path="/cart" component={Cart} />
  <Route exact path="/" component{HomePage}
  <Route component={Default} />
</Switch>
```

You'll notice I changed your base route `/` to point to a `HomePage` component that I know you have not implemented. It's just there as an example for how to complete your routing setup.

Comment: Thank you dear Sir! That was the solution!